# Is there any way to add nice CSS effects to this form code?

Tags: html, css

Basiaclly, I am trying to make a upload form for my website. I was wondering if there is any CSS that would make this look much more pleasing and unique. The code below is only HTML. I only need the CSS but if you find any way to improve the HTML, let me know.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Form</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

        <form action = "index.php" method="post" enctype="mutlipart/form-data">

        <label for="file">Choose a file:</label>

        <input type="file" name="file1"/>

        <input type="submit" value="send!"/>

        </form>



      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could improve is change the `<input type="submit" value="send!"/>` code to `<button id="" class="" type="submit">Your Text Here</button>`. Also for css codes for like buttons I reccomend use something like this

```
ButtonIDHere {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

and to make inputs a little nicer use something like this

```
.InputClass {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 730px;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

Also maybe change the border color and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

yo so what do you actually wanna see I just made the form centred and added some colour. 
do u want the buttons to look nicer?
https://jsfiddle.net/jqc05Ldk/5/

```
.container{
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 24px 24px;
background-color: #57b3e4;
height: auto;
  color: #BBDEF0;
      border-radius: 25px;

}

input[type="submit"]{
    border-radius: 25px;
border: 4px #00A6A6 solid;
background-color: #00A6A6;
color:#BBDEF0;
cursor:pointer;

}

input[type="submit"]:hover{
color: #00A6A6;
background-color: #BBDEF0;

}
```

Comment: If you can make the buttons nicer, that would be great.

Comment: its kinda hard as ur html for the inputs are hard to call upon

Comment: i made the send button looks sorta better but the other one is harder like what i said above

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks for the help.

Comment: yo i made the send button look like a button now hopefully its what you want

Comment: and if u dont have a colour scheme i just got mine from here https://coolors.co/

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect. Also, do you know how you would make a popup that once you press send, it says "Thanks, your papers will be evaluated"?

Comment: well i use jquery and i would use an on click function something like $('.send_btn').on('click', function () { alert("Thanks, your papers will be evaluated");});

Answer (score 0):

For these type of file inputs you can use form control in bootstrap which does not include the external css that much because bootstrap is a css framework and the button styling also will be nice when we use bootstrap Try this code.This code also includes the alert that comes after send button.Try doing these type of forms with bootstrap

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Form</title>
     <style>
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 25px;

    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function showMessage(){
    alert("Thanks Your papers have been evaluated");
  }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <form action = "index.php" method="post" enctype="mutlipart/form-data">
  <div class="container mt-4 mb-2">
    <form>
   <div class="form-group mt-2">
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Example file input</label>
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
<button type="submit" onclick = "showMessage()"class="btn btn-primary mt-2">send </button>
</div>
</form>
```